# In CMake, how can I find the imported target after calling find_package?

Tags: build, cmake, package, package-managers

CMake [`find_package`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/command/find_package.html) documentation says:

> When the package is found package-specific information is provided through variables and Imported Targets documented by the package itself.

If I have a library, `ABCD` which I can get using `find_package`, provided CMake can locate a suitable `ABCDConfig.cmake` file. It then creates the Imported Target(s) (e.g. `abcd10 abcdExtra`) as mentioned above.

Then I can compile and link against these libraries like so:

```
target_include_directories(mytarget abcd10 abcdExtra)
target_link_libraries(mytarget abcd10 abcdExtra)
```

The problem is, depending on how the contents of that `ABCDConfig.cmake` file, which somebody else wrote, the names of the targets could be almost anything (e.g. `abcdlib`,`abcdX64`,`Foobar`,...), even though it might be the exact same library `ABCD`!

I've Looked through much of the documentation, but I can't see any methods to get the Imported Targets, so it looks like I have to know what all the common imported target names are, and check for them individually. This seems a little bit unreasonable to me. Am I missing something here? How can I load and link against libraries generated by different package managers (or even someone who wrote their own `ABCDConfig.cmake` file) without knowing these specifics?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How can I load and link against libraries generated by different package managers (or even someone who wrote their own ABCDConfig.cmake file) without knowing these specifics?

You cannot.

The only way is to **read documentation** about specific `ABCDConfig.cmake` file. Such documentation is usually written at the beginning of the file (as comments).

CMake doesn't enforce anything about `ABCDConfig.cmake` files, so only the author of the file knows how to use it.

While CMake provides some support for generating config files (see [install(EXPORTS)](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/command/install.html#installing-exports) command), only the author of the project knows meaning of the imported targets.